# Emulator Manager Not Launching in Tizen Studio

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator

**NOTE: I am new to Tizen Development, so please keep that in mind when answering or commenting.**

I have recently installed Tizen Studio. I started a new sample web-based project for Wearable 4.0 using the TouchPaint sample. When I try to open the emulator manager to run the sample, I get an error message that reads "*JAVA_HOME not set in env variables*" [newline] "*Please set the value and try again*".

I have also tried using the run command. If I use that, it will start up the emulator but will fail to launch the program. I see the "watch" with a black screen and some unformatted text, similar to a command line. It only completes the operation ("*Launching TouchPaintTest*") to 6%.

Anybody who knows about this out there, please answer my question as I am very interested in Tizen wearable development.

Comment: OS may be relevant. Is your JAVA_HOME set?

Comment: I am running Windows. No, I don't have JAVA_HOME set. How do I set it?

Comment: That's not hard to find out on your own. Google "Setup JDK".

Comment: @Mär, I was able to set JAVA_HOME and successfully launched the emulator manager. But when I run the project in the emulator I launched, it never makes it past the CLI-like state. I don't think the emulator is fully booting up. What is the solution for this?

Comment: Development machine environment please...? Windows/Mac/Linux ?

Comment: @Iqbalhossain, I am using **Tizen Studio** 3.0 on **Windows**.

Comment: Windows 10 .....?

Comment: @Iqbalhossain, Yes. I'm using Windows 10 on a Dell pc.

Comment: So far I know..... Tizen Studio has some problems on Windows 10 ....you may try on different like 8.1 or on 7

Comment: @Iqbalhossain I understand that, and it may work. The problem is I don't have another computer running 8.1 or 7, and at this point in time, I'm not willing to downgrade my one laptop for that.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the BIOS and enable the Intel VT.

https://www.howtogeek.com/213795/how-to-enable-intel-vt-x-in-your-computers-bios-or-uefi-firmware/

Then run the
`C:\tizen-studio\tools\emulator\etc\Intelhaxm.exe` file.

Comment: I booted into my PC's BIOS and enabled the relevant settings. As I have an AMD processor, there was an option for `Virtualization` rather than `Intel VT`. Turning this on did not solve the problem, and I couldn't run the file you mentioned because it doesn't work with an AMD CPU.